# Orthogonal Coordinates

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I'm hoping someone could give me a good definition of "orthogonal coordinates."  Attempts to find one online has left me only with a vague idea.  A reference text would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Orthogonal coordinates are coordinate surface which meet at right angles.

What are coordinate surfaces?
There are n dimensions in a coordinate system. A plane in which only one dmension's/coordinate's value is constant is called the coordinate surface. For ex
In a 3d coordinate system let x=3 be an equation of plane. This plane is a coordinate surface.

Now if in any coordinate system is such that all  coordinate surfaces are perpendicular then this surface is called orthogonal coordinate system.
For ex on a plane of paper draw coordinate axes and draw horizontal and vertical lines. Now this is a orthogonal coordinate system. If you keep one end of the page fixed and rotate it from the other end then this also is an orthogonal coordinate system.